# Reading an array consecutively with two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array : int[] arr = {5,4,3,1,2};

```
 I want to do like this::

 5 should be read by thread one
 4 should be read by thread two
 3 should be read by thread one
 1 should be read by thread two
 2 should be read by thread one
```

I have tried my best this simple program:

```
package com.techighost.create.deadlock;

public class ArrayReading implements Runnable {

    volatile int index = 0;

    int[] arr;

    public ArrayReading(int[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (arr) {
            for (;index<=(arr.length-1);) {
                if (index % 2 == 0  && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread-One")) {
                    System.out.println(arr[index] + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    index++;
                    arr.notify();

                } else if (index % 2 != 0 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread-Two")) {
                    System.out.println(arr[index] + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    index++;
                    arr.notify();

                }else{
                    System.out.println("In else " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    try {
                        arr.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int[] arr = { 5, 4, 3, 1, 2 };
        ArrayReading arrayReading = new ArrayReading(arr);
        Thread t = new Thread(arrayReading);
        t.setName("Thread-One");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(arrayReading);
        t1.setName("Thread-Two");

        t.start();
        t1.start();

        t.join();
        t1.join();
    }
}
```

**I think that this thread name check should not be there? Any body please suggest what can be done to remove this check**

Comment: Why do you want this specific thread 1, 2, 1 pattern?  The whole nature of threads is supposed to be asynchronous and _not_ this orderly.  You should just submit the jobs from the array into an `ExecutorService` and let the threads process them in parallel.

Comment: @Gray I was trying something. and i thought check on thread name is not kool

Comment: If you want your tasks to run sequentially, run them sequentially. If you want them to run in parallel, expect random interleaving...

Answer (score 3):

You can use condition as mentioned by @zzk.Program
for this can be as

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class PrintSequentially {

private final int[] items;
private final ReentrantLock lock;
private final Condition notEven;
private final Condition notOdd;

private int currentCount = 0;

public PrintSequentially(int[] items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    this.notEven = lock.newCondition();
    this.notOdd = lock.newCondition();
}

public void printSeq() throws InterruptedException {

    try {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        while (currentCount < items.length) {
            if (currentCount % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":"
                        + items[currentCount++]);
                if (currentCount < items.length)
                    notEven.await();
                notOdd.signal();
            } else {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":"
                        + items[currentCount++]);
                notEven.signal();
                if (currentCount < items.length)
                    notOdd.await();
            }
        }

    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

}

Driver program for this is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] ={1,2,3,4,5};
    final PrintSequentially p = new PrintSequentially(arr);

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                p.printSeq();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                p.printSeq();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread th1 = new Thread(r1);
    th1.setName("thread 1");
    th1.start();

    Thread th2 = new Thread(r2);
    th2.setName("thread 2");
    th2.start();

}
```

Here you can add as many thread you want. It will print sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditions. Thread 1 should wait for condition index % 2 == 0 and Thread 2 should wait for condition index % 2 == 1.

Look at this link for [how to use condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

Comment: `index & 1` would be more efficient even/odd check.

Comment: In general this assumes the thread work item runtime is invariant - unlikely to be extensible in the real world.  That's a problem of the question, not your answer though.

Comment: @zzk I want to remove the thread name check...Again in your solution, I need to give the thread name check.

Comment: @Cam No. You have different run() function for two threads. No names needed for thread.

Comment: @zzk Do not use Threads, use Runnables executed by Executors.

Comment: @zzk but I have also one more condition that first thread one should print the value at index 0 and then thread 2 should print the value at index 1 and so on. It should not happen that index 3 is printed before index 1. i hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @Cam after thread 1 read a value at index i, it increases the index to i+1, now it has to wait for thread 2 to read the value at index i+1 before thread 1 can read i+2 (it has to wait for thread 2 to increase the index).

Answer (score 1):

Use another parameter field in your runnable to tell it to read even or odd indices, create two instances of your runnable, one for even, one for odd. Set up an `ExecutorService` with at least two threads, execute the runnables. It may be possibile they finish too fast to be given different threads. Did not test this.

Comment: I didn't read this in the question, but if you really want them to print in order, you could use two Semaphores, also supplied to the Runnables. Semaphore _even_ is acquired by the first runnable, that must print 0, before it releases Semaphore _odd_. The other Runnable acquires from _odd_ (which makes it wait until the first Runnable finished its first loop cycle). Then it releases _even_. Semaphores must be created with 1 permit for even and 0 for odd. But it's been said before, this is a silly threading example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use inter thread communication using `wait` and `notify` like this :

```
class ReadNum
{
    int arr[];
    private volatile int counter = 0;
    public ReadNum()
    {
        counter = 0 ;
    }
    public ReadNum(int size)
    {
        arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
    }
    public void setArray(int[] arr)
    {
        counter = 0;
        this.arr = arr;
    }
    public synchronized void  readOdd()
    {
        while (counter < arr.length)
        {
            if (counter % 2 != 0)
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":->"+arr[counter]);
                counter++;
            }
            notify();
            try{
                wait();
            }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
        notify();//So that other EvenThread does'nt hang if OddThread completes earlier
    }
    public synchronized void  readEven()
    {
        while (counter < arr.length)
        {
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":->"+arr[counter]);
                counter++;
            }
             notify();
            try{
                wait();
            }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
        notify();//So that other OddThread does'nt hang if EvenThread completes earlier
    }
}
public class SequenceRead
{
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        final ReadNum rn = new ReadNum();
        int arr[]= {1,2,34,78,99,45,4545,987,343,45};
        rn.setArray(arr);
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                rn.readEven();
            }
        },"EvenReadThread");
        Thread th2 = new Thread( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                rn.readOdd();
            }
        },"OddReadThread");
        th2.start();th1.start();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the explanation that you asked for about Race Condition.

> **Race Condition** : *"It is a situation where multiple threads can access same resource  (typically object's instance variables) and can
>   produce corrupted data if one thread "races in" or "sneaks in" too
>   quickly before an operation that should be atomic has completed. Hence the output of program is unpredictable because it is dependent on the sequence or timing of starting, execution and completion of the various threads accessing the same resource ."*

For example consider the code given below:

```
class Race
{
    private int counter;
    public void printCounter()
    {
        while(counter < 100)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);//Added to show Race Effect.
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" : "+counter);//If we don't consider Race condition then the Output should be 100 for all threads. 
    }
}
public class MainClasss
{
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        final Race race = new Race();
        Thread[] th = new Thread[2];
        //Creating 2 threads to call printCounter of object race
        for (int i = 0 ; i < th.length ; i++)
        {
            th[i] = new Thread( new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    race.printCounter();
                }
            }, "Thread"+i);
        }
        //Starting all Threads
        for (Thread thr : th )          
        {
            thr.start();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output that that I am getting , It might vary on your system.

```
Thread1 : 100
Thread0 : 101
```

All threads are not printing 100 as expected!!! **Why** ? Because Program has no control on when an executing Thread will be preempted  by another thread.It all depends upon JVM Thread Scheduler.
One of the possible explanations for above output is as follows:

> 1. At counter = 99 , Thread1 sneaked inside the while loop and slept for 10 ms .
> 2. JVM Scheduler now preempted Thread1 by Thread0 .
> 3. Thread1 goes inside "while" loop because it finds counter < 100
> 4. At Thread.sleep Thread0 is preempted by Thread1.
> 5. Thread1 increases the counter by 1.
> 6. Thread1 prints the counter value as 100 and finishes.
> 7. Thread0 continues execution and increases the counter by 1 and makes counter = 101
> 8. Thread0 prints the counter value as 101 and finishes.

This is the live exhibition of Race Condition.
To Avoid this Race condition you should make the `ReadNum` method as synchronized , So that when a Thread enters that method , it takes the monitor and become owner of the synchronized method . And that thread is preempted only after it completes the all operation **Atomically** . I hope it gave you a good overview of Race Condition now.

Comment: It suffers from the same problems as the OP.  The last thread is going to hang at the `wait` with no one to `notify`.  And it is a confusing  rewrite of already confused code.  I don't see how it helps the OP at all.

Comment: @Gray: nice point out..but that hang problem is resolved.. Now what is confusing aspect of this code ? can you explain ?

Comment: Threaded applications are complex as your initial bug demonstrated.  Our job as answerers is to help the OP understand and improve their code -- not to provide another solution.

Comment: @Gray: So according to you `Thread` is no longer the reliable choice for such tasks?? And i have just enhanced the OP code more clearly and in understandable design.

Comment: @Gray: Just putting a link to some site which contains some example or just telling OP that use this class without providing its implementation to fulfill the OP's just increases the burden on OP instead of solving his/her issue.. So i prefer  providing the complete information and implementation of code..

Comment: I disagree completely.  How does providing another implementation help the OP understand how to write this code?  And maybe his example code is only a portion of his problem.  So he's going to have to take your code and rework it into his solution.

Comment: @Gray: I don't consider it as another implementation. In fact asking OP to use `ThreadPool` and other concepts and terms would confuse him/her more . He might would have to change many portion of his code to incorporate the new `classes` and `packets` . The code that i have posted is just the enhanced version of what OP wants to carry on with.

Comment: Although this toy excercise should not be taken too seriously IMO, I think @VishalK supplied adequate code for the question asked. The problem lies in the question. In any case, production code should be based on the abstractions provided by `java.util.concurrent` rather than old-fashioned notify/wait tricks mixed with hand-rolled threads.

Comment: @VishalK sometimes this program runs ..sometime got hanged :(

Comment: @VishalK when you start the main program, it just got hanged..nothing prints on the console. I observed it two or three times..i am also looking for the reason why this is happening :(

Comment: @Cam: Yes it will happen..my mistake here..I can't post code here.. i can tell you what to do.. int readOdd() and readEven() remove code 'notify();
  try{
  wait();
  }catch(Exception ex){}' written within if block and write it outside the if block overriding the `notify()` already written over there. And after the while loop write `notify()`.

Comment: @VishalK Would you please explain me the race condition. Why it is hanging? And How did you identify this please?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this probably is some sort of getting-your-feet-wet thread application but there are a number of problems with it that makes it less than optimal.

1. The whole point of using threads is asynchronous operation.  Wanting your threads to process every other entry in an array sounds like you are dividing up the work but this may run slower than single threaded because of the synchronization to accomplish the every other.  The nature of threads also means that "2" may be printed before "1".  That's a good thing because you aren't slowing down a thread to get them to be in order.
2. Your code has some race conditions here.  For example, a thread could process the last element of the list and go to `wait` but the other thread could have already finished the list and won't be there to `notify` it.  I bet your application often hangs at the end.
3. You should consider using an [executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) and submitting a job for each entry.  This is the best way to do most threaded task:

   ```
   // create a thread pool with 2 workers
   ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
   for (int entry : arr) {
       threadPool.submit(new `(entry));
   }
   // once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
   threadPool.shutdown();
   // to wait for the jobs to finish you do
   threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   ...
   ```

   Then your `ArrayReading` takes the entry *not* the whole array and can work on them independently.
4. Lastly, as others have already mentioned, you could pass a `boolean even` flag to have each thread process even (if true) or odd (if false) items.

   ```
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new ArrayReading(arr, true));
   Thread t2 = new Thread(new ArrayReading(arr, false));
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, You have talked about some race conditions in my code, Did you mean the last thread will print the value and moved to wait state, and the second thread got finished earlier, so nobody would be there to notify the first one..and my application hangs. Am I right?

Comment: if I want to maintain the execution order of the two threads, I think I can't use the approach suggested by you. Nowhere execution order comes into picture the solution you have provided. Am I right?

Comment: You mean to say, there is no point of taking care of execution order if you are using multi-threading..right?

Comment: I'm saying that forcing execution order and other synchronous behavior negates most of the benefits of threading your code @cam.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code you are looking for ....

```
public class ThreadConcurrent  {
    int []array=new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    volatile int i=0;

public  void checkSum() {
    synchronized (this) {
        for(;i<array.length;){
            System.out.println("thread name "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "  : "+array[i]);
            i++;
            notify();
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final ThreadConcurrent er=new ThreadConcurrent();       
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            er.checkSum();

        }
    }, "T1");
    Thread t21=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            er.checkSum();

        }
    }, "T2");
    t1.start();
    t21.start();
}
```

}